# ffmpeg: How to slow down a video for a while

Tags: video, ffmpeg, framerate

I want to reduce the speed of a video with FFmpeg for x seconds, after that it should be playing like before.
Is there a way to do that in ffmpeg using `setpts` parameter?
I only found [this FFmpeg doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) to set up the **whole** Speed-Level.

Rightnow ffmpeg is reading an Image-folder with about 200 images to create a Video using:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i 'image2/*.png' -vf fps=25/1 -s 640x360 -b 2000k output.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg does not have a direct way to get this done. What you can do is split the video into slices, apply the slow motion to each slice and concatenate all together again. `filter_complex` can be used with filter chaining for this.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=0:10[v1];
[0:v]trim=10:30[v2];
[0:v]trim=start=30[v3];
[v2]setpts=PTS/0.5[slowv];
[v1][slowv][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map [outv] map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output_video
```

As you are manipulating the video you may need to re-encode the stream. For that you can select an appropriate codec from [here](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, look above my ffmpeg snip, i already have these images.

Comment: @user293004 Well this is not clear... what do you need exactly?